# MySQL - связать поле таблицы с другим полем этой же таблицы

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Есть БД, в ней Primary key это поле name (varchar 255).
И есть поле main (varchar 255).
Поле main связано с полем name через FOREIGN KEY.

Теперь, я хочу изменить поле name в одной записи, и чтобы все записи у которых стоит такое же main, поменялись автоматом.

```
| adels | CREATE TABLE `adels` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `main` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `main` (`main`),
  CONSTRAINT `adels_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`main`) REFERENCES `adels` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Начальные записи:

```
perm_name, perm_desc, NULL 
role_name, role_desc, perm_name
```

Надо, чтобы поменяв значение perm_name на perm_name2, таблица приняла следующий вид:

```
perm_name2, perm_desc, NULL 
role_name, role_desc, perm_name2
```

Но при попытке изменить эту строку выходит оши

```
UPDATE `adels` SET `name` = 'perm_name2' WHERE `adels`.`name` = 'perm_name'

#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`full`.`adels`, CONSTRAINT `adels_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`main`) REFERENCES `adels` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL recurses to update *the same table* it has previously updated during the cascade, **it acts like RESTRICT**. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations.

Comment: То есть, если CASCADE на поле той же самой таблицы, то оно будет действовать как RESTRICT?

Comment: Для зацикленных каскадных операций - да. А в Вашем конкретном случае бОльшее внимание надо уделить второму предложению, в котором написано безальтернативное "нельзя".

Comment: нельзя использовать ON UPDATE CASCADE для полей одной таблицы. Так?

Comment: Да, именно так. Или если точнее - использовать в DDL можно, но выполнять каскадные операции обновления связанных полей не получится. При этом связанные записи (поле main) обновлять можно, если есть соответствующие записи на стороне "один" - впрочем, для этого в DDL не нужны каскадные операции.